# Layout problems - Java

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am using GridBagLayout in a project I've been working on, the problem is that when I compile in my computer or in others at my uni it shows properly how I want it to be.

[image: Proper way]

But when I run it on a different PC it is displayed different, the top-left panel and the radar panel are not like they should be.

[image: Wrong way]

We both have the same JDK and use NetBeans 7.3, so I don't know where the problem is.

This is the method I am using to add the panels to the frame.

```
private void agregarPaneles() {

    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    add(scrollerVuelos, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    add(panelEstado, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    add(panelOrdenes, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 3;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    add(panelRadar, gbc);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted in not enough to give you an exact answer, but in general:

If GridBagLayout doesn't have enough space to display a component at its preferred size it will then use the minimum size of the component. Since many components have a small minimum size the component can get shrunk to almost nothing.

So you may need to look at setting minimum sizes on your panels. You can also look at the weightX and weighty values as they have an impact on how a component is resized.

Read the Swing tutorial on `How to Use GridBagLayout` for more information and examples.

Also remember you can use nested panels with different layout managers if that makes the layout easier. For example maybe the main layout should be a BorderLayout. Then in the NORTH you add a panel using a GridLayout. In the CENTER you add your other panel.

Comment: Indeed, I set the minimun size and it worked fine, still I can't understand why did it worked in some computers and not in others with the same jdk.

Comment: @sandiego Because different computers use different rendering techniques, font metrics and other elements which introduce suitables into the system, this is why you should always us a layout manager ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the preferred size of the component does not fit within the available space of the frame and `GridBagLayout` is reverting to use the components minimum size instead.

You could use `GridBagConstraints#weightx` and `GridBagConstraints#weighty` and `GridBagConstraints#fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH` to try and force the component to use the entire available space of the cell it's within

You should also be using `Frame#pack` to pack the frame rather then setting it's size manually, this will attempt to size of the frame so that it can meet the requirements of the contents preferred size